# invisible header on printing page

Tags: html, css, printing

I noticed that Chrome doesn't accept thead as a header of the printing page anymore.

Now I'm using position fixed, but that has a "content size" of zero. To get around that I created a wrapper with a fixed size. But that works just on the first page. On the second page there is not wrapper and because of that the header is over the text.

Is there a way to tell position fixed that it should push the content down?

```
<style>
    #headerWrapper {
        display: block;
        height: 50px;
    }

    @media print {
        #header {
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            width:100%;
            color:#CCC;
            background:#333;
            padding:8px;
            margin-left: 100px;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="headerWrapper">
        <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    </div>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share your codes.

Comment: now there is a example :)

Comment: 1st page 2nd page in the sense scrolling up and down?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When you open the code in your browser and press CTRL+P for printing, the preview shows that the header on the second page is over the content

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution works fine for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
  
header {
  font-size: 20px;  
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  } 
  header {
    position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   padding-bottom:5mm;
  }

  p {   
 padding:5mm;
  }
}
   
</style>

<body>
    <header>Header </header> 
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
    <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope, run the code, open the printer preview and scroll down to the second page

Comment: Posted the updated solution,let me know if the issue still exists.

Comment: isn't working, the padding from the first and second page of the content is not equal

Comment: I tried to reduce it, but the 2nd page and 3rd page has different spacing comparing with first :/ .Working on it,Once I get it I'll update the answer.

Comment: well that is what I'm talking about. how can I create a printing preview that has a header on each dynamic page?

Comment: Check the latest one,I tried to minimize it,except first page the alignments are same on the rest of the pages.Give me some time :)

Comment: No it's like the some one. The whole thing is, that I have multiple "documents" and they need the same header, so I need the same space at every page